# ToolTip of a WPF Custom Control with Custom Control's property value

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, custom-controls, tooltip

In a WPF application I have a Custom Control.

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlStatusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ControlStatus", typeof(int), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(16));

    public int ControlStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(ControlStatusProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ControlStatusProperty, value);
            ChangeVisualState(false);
        }
    }
 ...
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
       ...
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(this, "Status: " + ControlStatus);          
    }

    private void ChangeVisualState(bool useTransitions)
    {
       ...
       ToolTipService.SetToolTip(this, "Status: " + ControlStatus);
    }
```

The problem is: ToolTip always shows the value of `ControlStatus` property which had been at the moment of `OnApplyTemplate()` method execution.
The `ControlStatus` property of a custom control have been changed during run-time, but the ToolTip still always shows initial value.

**How could I make the ToolTip of a Custom Control always show the current value of Custom Control's property?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use binding instead of statically setting the tool tip with `ToolTipService.SetToolTip`. In your case it should be like this:

```
SetBinding(ToolTipProperty, new Binding
                            {
                                Source = this,
                                Path = new PropertyPath("ControlStatus"),
                                StringFormat = "Status: {0}"
                            });
```

Comment: Yes! It works great! +1 Could you, please, to help understand: How to set a ToolTip with multiple properties. Something like: `"Property1Value: " + Property1 + "\n" + "Property2Value: " + Property2 + "\n"`

Comment: @rem - In this case you can use `MultiBinding` instead of just `Binding`. In `MultiBinding` you will have `StringFormat` set to "Property1Value: {0}\nProperty2Value: {1}\n" and its `Bindings` collection will contain `Binding` objects for each property.

Comment: Thanks, Pavlo! Your answer's really helpful and it fully answered this my original question, so I've accepted it. I have some problems in implementing MultiBinding approach so I opened a separate question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371552/wpf-custom-controls-tooltip-multibinding-problem