# WPF Custom Control's ToolTip MultiBinding problem

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, custom-controls, tooltip

When I set a ToolTip Binding In a WPF Custom Control, this way it works perfect:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
   ...
    SetBinding(ToolTipProperty, new Binding
                        {
                            Source = this,
                            Path = new PropertyPath("Property1"),
                            StringFormat = "ValueOfProp1: {0}"
                        });          
}
```

But when I try to use MultiBinding to have several properties in the ToolTip, it doesn't work:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
   ...
    MultiBinding multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
    multiBinding.StringFormat = "ValueOfProp1: {0}\nValueOfProp2: {1}\nValueOfProp3: {2}\n";

        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding
        {
            Source = this,
            Path = new PropertyPath("Property1")
        });
        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding
        {
            Source = this,
            Path = new PropertyPath("Property2")
        });
        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding
        {
            Source = this,
            Path = new PropertyPath("Property3")
        });

        this.SetBinding(ToolTipProperty, multiBinding);          
}
```

In this case I have no ToolTip shown at all.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `StringFormat` on `MultiBinding` works only on properties of type `string`, while the `ToolTip` property is of type `object`. In this case the `MultiBinding` requires a value converter defined.

As a workaround you could set a `TextBlock` as a `ToolTip` and bind its `Text` property using `MultiBinding` (since `Text` is of type `string` it'll work with `StringFormat`):

```
TextBlock toolTipText = new TextBlock();

MultiBinding multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
multiBinding.StringFormat = "ValueOfProp1: {0}\nValueOfProp2: {1}\nValueOfProp3: {2}\n";

multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding
{
    Source = this,
    Path = new PropertyPath("Property1")
});
multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding
{
    Source = this,
    Path = new PropertyPath("Property2")
});
multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding
{
    Source = this,
    Path = new PropertyPath("Property3")
});

toolTipText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, multiBinding);

ToolTip = toolTipText;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm! +1 I'll accept your answer a bit later to let you aquire more rep points. Thanks once again!